# CSS Overflow:hidden not working on my slider

Tags: html, css

I created 100% width slide with jQuery. My slide is working but overflow x plane not hiding. My codes;

Html,

```
<div class="slide">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="inc/imj/slide/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="inc/imj/slide/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="inc/imj/slide/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="reff">
        <span class="before">
            <img src="inc/imj/before.jpg" alt="" />
        </span>
        <span class="after">
            <img src="inc/imj/after.jpg" alt="" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS,

```
.slide{
    border-bottom:1px solid orange;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    width:140%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.slide ul li img{width:1400px;height:400px;}
.slide ul li{display:inline-block;list-style-type:none;}
.slide span.before img{border-radius:40px 40px 40px 40px;}
.slide span.before img:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.slide span.after img{border-radius:40px 40px 40px 40px;}
.slide span.after img:hover{cursor:pointer;}

.slide .reff{
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:-35px;
    left:-250px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Result,

[image]

So, x scrollbar is active I want x scrollbar to hidden. But doen't work.

How we do solve?
Thank you for interest..

Good Works..

Note: This is web site, I did for Improve myself. Money could not have gained. This isn't the actual job. This is job my hobby.

Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `width:140%;` set in your CSS

Comment: If this solved your problem please be sure to check the check mark.